# Is it possible to include one Caffe's prototxt file in another?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

Caffe requires at least three `.prototxt` files: for training, for deployment and to define solver parameters.

My training and deployment files contain identical pieces, describing network architecture. Is it possible to refactor this, by moving this common part out of them into a separate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for "all-in-one" network.
See [this github discussion](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3863) for more information.

Apparently, you can achieve this by using not only `include {phase: XXX}`, but also take advantage of `stage` and `state`.